# Are End(V), GL(V) and Hom(V,W) Groups or Vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, representation-theory

I am reading a book about Representation Theory of Finite Groups and in the book it gives:

$End(W) \cong M_n(\mathbb{C})$
$GL(V) \cong GL_n(\mathbb{C})$
$Hom(V,W) \cong M_{mn}(\mathbb{C})$

$V$ and $W$ are Vector Spaces and $Hom(V,W) = \{A:V\rightarrow W | A$ is a linear map$\}$, $End(V) = Hom(V,V)$ and $GL(V) = \{A \in End(V)|A$ is invertible$\}$

I understand what these sets are, but in the above relations I was unsure whether they are being considered as groups (With group operation composition of maps/multiplication of matrices) or as vector spaces (with addition of maps/matrices and scalar multiplication by scalars in $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: "Benjamin Steinberg - Representation Theory of Finite Groups: An Introductory Approach"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\operatorname{End}(W) \cong M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras (i.e. as rings as well as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces),
$\operatorname{GL}(V) \cong \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ as groups, and $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W) \cong M_{mn}(\mathbb{C})$ as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces.

**EDIT**

Note that $\operatorname{End}(W)$ is not a group wrt composition (as it contains non-invertible elements) and $\operatorname{GL(V)}$ is not a vector space (as it doesn't contain an additive zero element, for example). So there is no way to read all three $\cong$ signs uniformly as "isomorphic as vector spaces" nor uniformly as "isomorphic as multiplicative groups".

Comment: I would have thought they would all be either groups or vector spaces since the three relations are given together.

Comment: @123123 No, that's not possible. $\operatorname{End}(W)$ is not a group, and $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is not a vector space, so no way to read all $\cong$ signs as "isomorphic as gropus" nor as "isomorphic as vector spaces".

Comment: Right, because the linear map would need to be invertible to be a group! And GL(V) is not a vector space because the sum of two invertible matrices is not necessarily invertible. Thank you.

Comment: I removed my downvote. I'm really sorry to bother you.

Comment: @Nightflight thank you!

Comment: $End(V)$ is not a group *under multiplication.* As a vector space, or as a ring, it is always a group under addition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews well...you are right of course. "isomorphic as vector spaces" implies "isomorphic as (additive) groups", so what I wrote is not strictly true. But I guess that "as a group" referred to the multiplicative structure. I guess I will remove the addition from my answer again.